# Send Welcome Email PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email

Currently I have a simple PHP script(s) that accept the users email address and write it to a MySQL database. The code below is all working fine.

How can I go about adding a function to email the new subscriber a bit of information to the address they provided?

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php'; // database information

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password)
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)
  or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql="INSERT INTO users (email)
VALUES ('$email')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
header('Location: ../thankyou.php');
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not the answer but wow. Heard of sql injections?

Comment: simple google search of 'php email' will easily give you multiple answers. look up the `mail()` function.

Comment: I'm a total PHP noob. Can you direct me on where I need to worry about SQL injections, and what I can do to stop them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php your own questions doesn't seem investigated at all. To stop being a noob you need to be able to search for answers on your own. Google is a way to start.

Answer (score 1):

to answer your question, it should be something like this

```
email($new_subscribers_email_address,"topic goes here","message goes here");
```

btw note that you should NOT be using mysql_  , and that mysql_ will be removed from php soon. use PDO or MySQLi instead..

also note that you have a SQL Injection vulnerability here

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES ('$email')";
```

solution: mysql_real_escape_string  , like

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."')";
```